# Using the results of conditional inside Concat Statement

Tags: mysql

Essentially I am trying to use the results of a conditional inside a Concat Statement that follows it right after.

Inside my `SELECT` Statement I have the following:

```
  IF (`Table1`.`Address1` IS NULL, `Table1 `.`Address2`, CONCAT_WS(",", Address1, Address2)) AS Shipping_Address,
  
  CONCAT_WS(", ", Shipping_Address, Table1.City, Table1.State, Table1.Zip) AS AddressFull
```

But when Shipping_Address inside the conditional I get no results, meaning it seems to be unable to display results from the conditional before.

Can the results of the first expression somehow be used in the Concat that follows it?

Comment: There are some operations where it's better to use `CASE` than `IF` .. but to understand more, can you please provide some example data, your current generated result and your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Shipping_Address is a column alias

you cannot  use alias in select  you should repated the code

```
IF (`Table1`.`Address1` IS NULL, `Table1 `.`Address2`, CONCAT_WS(",", Address1, Address2)) AS Shipping_Address,

CONCAT_WS(", ",IF (`Table1`.`Address1` IS NULL, `Table1 `.`Address2`, CONCAT_WS(",", Address1, Address2)), Table1.City, Table1.State, Table1.Zip) AS AddressFull
```